# Should I use exceptions to check for invalid parameters in a constructor?

Tags: oop, exception

I just read in Code Complete that you should not use exceptions for flow control. I also know that the common advice is to use exceptions to handle "exceptional cases." But I'm not sure how to apply this advice. Is it a good idea to use exceptions to check for invalid parameters in a constructor? For instance, I have an ExcelInputConverter that turns rows in a spreadsheet into Record objects (for manipulation). The constructor takes the name of an excel file as input. Should I use exceptions to check that the incoming strings are valid excel files? That the excel files exist? It seems like I should use exceptions here because if this happens, the class essentially can't function.

Is it a good idea to check for invalid data within the class or outside of the class?

```
Public Sub New(filename as string) 'new excel input converter
      If Not (Path.GetExtension(fileName) = ".xls" Or Path.GetExtension(fileName) = ".xlsx") Then Throw New Exception("Can't make an Excel input converter from a non-Excel file like " & inputFileName)
      If Not (File.Exists(fileName)) Then Throw New Exception("This file does not exist. Can't make an Excel converter")
```

Comment: There really isn't any other way to tell the program that the constructor failed so using an exception there is the correct, and only, way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object cannot be constructed due to an invalid argument to a constructor, an Exception is appropriate.  Most languages do not provide a different means of telling the object creator that something went wrong (other than perhaps setting an "Invalid" flag on the object, which I would not suggest).

.NET defines an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) for this type of situation.

> Is it a good idea to check for invalid data within the class or outside of the class?

The class is in the best position to know what data is valid for it.  If the class evolves over time and the rules for valid data change, you don't want to have to go change all of the code that uses that class to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use exceptions as a last resort. For something like file-checking, i do: 
(PsuedoCode)

```
try
{
    fileToCheck = getUserInput();
    while(!fileToCheck.Exists() && quit==false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File does not exist. Make sure the path and filename are correct.");
        quit = getQuitInput();
        fileToCheck = getUserInput();
    }
    // fopen(fileToCheck) and other processes. Include other sub-try/catch blocks as needed.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fatal Error Occurred. Check Log files for information.");
    logError(e);
}
```

This way, the user can attempt to fix their own user-error problems that may occur and only in more complicated cases that they cannot fix (excel file gets corrupted or something) does the program terminate

Comment: That doesn't really address the OP's question of whether they are appropriate in a constructor...

Comment: I generally use this concept throughout my code, so if a constructor is being created from input values, it would attempt the validate the parameters before passing to a constructor in the first place. If any user input validation *needs* to happen in the constructor and cant be done in the UI scope, then it wouldnt be feasible to re-ask the user for data (for example, creating 1000 objects with bad inputs), so exceptions would be better